# A method that returns an array with no duplicates

Tags: java, arrays

I am supposed to implement a method in Java that returns an array of integers with no duplicates. I have managed to do it, but my solution seems rather long. I would like to know of ways to improve it.

I added comments so it is easier for your guys to understand what the code does.

```
public class IntArrayProcessor {

    private int[] a;

    public IntArrayProcessor(int[] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return Array with no repeated integers.
     */
    public int[] getSet() {
        /* creates an array with the same entries and length as this.a */
        int[] duplicateA = new int[this.a.length];

        /* stores the number of repeated entries in array this.a */
        int numberOfDuplicates = 0;

        /* is the integer a duplicate or not? */
        boolean isDuplicate;

        /**
         * Counts the number of duplicates in array this.a
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < this.a.length; i++) {
            duplicateA[i] = this.a[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < duplicateA.length; i++) {
            isDuplicate = false;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < this.a.length; j++) {
                if (duplicateA[i] == this.a[j]) {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                }
            }
            if (isDuplicate) {
                numberOfDuplicates++;
            }
        }

        /*
         * the noDuplicate array has the lenght of the this.a array minus the
         * number of repeated entries
         */
        int[] noDuplicate = new int[this.a.length - numberOfDuplicates];

        /* to keep track of the noDuplicate indexes */
        numberOfDuplicates = 0;

        /**
         * An array with no repeated numbers
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < duplicateA.length; i++) {
            isDuplicate = false;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < this.a.length; j++) {
                if (duplicateA[i] == this.a[j]) {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                }
            }
            if (!(isDuplicate)) {
                noDuplicate[numberOfDuplicates] = duplicateA[i];
                numberOfDuplicates++;
            }
        }
        return noDuplicate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, your instincts were correct, that's pretty long. There are multiple ways this could be solved, e.g., use a set or hash, iterate multiple times, use a collection class to store each unique entry and convert to an array on exit, etc.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a HashSet? That would solve all your problems instantly, as it disallowes duplicate entries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DaveNewton. No, I couldn't use any of those things. But I will keep them in mind so when I learned them I can revisit this problem and come up with a more straightforward solution! Thank you guys!

Comment: @Andreas Should I delete this post and post it again on codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @yagosansz Yes.

Comment: Just sort the array, then eliminate identical neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to use the Stream API:

```
int[] distinctArray = IntStream.of(a).distinct().toArray();
```

If you don't want to use Stream API you can use a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) (or other collections that implement the [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface).

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

That is some rather long code! It seems like you are looking for a more homemade solution than the one that Max put up! Here is some psuedo-code for what I would do: 
 
1. Create a dictionary that takes an `int` and returns a `boolean`. 
2. For every element in your starting array add it to the dictionary with the `boolean` value of `true` (even though the value *won't* actually matter). 
3. Find the number of keys in your dictionary (this will be the number of unique values found in the first array, which is also the length of your new array) 
4. Create a new array given the length found in the previous step.
5. Run through each of the keys in the dictionary and add it to the new array!

Shortcut: Instead of step 4 & 5 typically getting the keys from the dictionary will return an array, which would be your end solution.

I'd be happy to write up a more formal solution if that is more helpful. 
 
Note: If you are only familiar with Java, Dictionaries are *almost* synonymous to HashMaps and *can* be used interchangeably in this situation. Java's *default implementation* of a dictionary is called a `HashMap` 
Note 2: Accessing the number of keys/getting all of the keys in a Dictionary/HashMap should be a function built-in, not one you have to write!